# how to plot multiple daily time series in one plot

Tags: r, plot

I have time series data of 27 days (from 2018-04-09 to 2018-5-15 without weekends) with 7 observations per day (08:00 t0 20:00 every two hours) with two variables per observation (di and eu).
I want to plot all days as line plots in one plot.

I found solutions to plot one plot per day with a ggplot facet plot and I found solutions to plot the whole timeseries in one plot (di and eu from 2018-04-09 to 2018-05-15).
But nothing that let me overlay 27 daily plots for one variable in one 8:00 to 20:00 plot.

The first three days as example data with dput():

```
structure(list(date_time = structure(c(1523260800, 1523268000, 
1523275200, 1523282400, 1523289600, 1523296800, 1523304000, 1523347200, 
1523354400, 1523361600, 1523368800, 1523376000, 1523383200, 1523390400, 
1523433600, 1523440800, 1523448000, 1523455200, 1523462400, 1523469600, 
1523476800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
di = c(75, 90, 35, 70, 75, 15, 5, 65, 55, 15, 15, 0, NA, 
15, 55, 55, 5, 25, NA, 60, NA), eu = c(15, 0, 65, 30, 15, 
65, 70, 40, 45, 75, 75, 100, NA, 85, 45, 30, 90, 65, NA, 
20, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

A plot with all 27 days in one plot may look confusing, but I like to try it, to see wether it makes a trend in the data obvious. A plot for each weekday would be a nice addition.

Comment: We miss the code we can help you with. Or do you want someone else to do your code for you?

Comment: I have code for the faceted plot or the two timelines in one plot. But both are not what I want to achieve. A function name or better search terms to google whould have been quite enough, but JasonAizkalns gave a full answer. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could determine the `day` and `hour` up front and then plot with respective groups like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  gather(metric, value, -date_time) %>%
  mutate(
    hour_of_day = hour(date_time),
    day = day(date_time)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hour_of_day, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = day)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ metric)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly what I wanted to achieve.